# Cleaning crumbs off the carpet of without vacuum

Tags: cleaning

The place where I sit is full of crumbs of things I eat. The cleaner was kicked out due to some theft, So now no cleaners. I don't have any vacuum (cannot afford one) that I can ask to clean the carpet where I have my chair. How can I make my space clean from cereal/chip crumbs on the carpet?

Comment: Buy a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: It's an office, I am here to work. @ajeh

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because house(office)keeping =/= home improvement.

Comment: "I am here to work" - Your duties specified in your employment contract probably do not mandate eating something at your desk every day. You could do your eating elsewhere. If the mess you make offends you, it is probably appropriate to take responsibility for the mess you create and do something yourself to prevent it or to clean it up.

Comment: @isherwood It is a DIY question, where I am asking how to clean a certain place without a vacuum

Comment: I would use a dustpan and brush to clean the existing mess, then take action to prevent making such a mess in future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7963/what-is-an-alternative-to-a-vacuum-cleaner-for-cleaning-carpets

Comment: A dog will pick up the crumbs for you. Of course, then you have the problem of removing dog hairs instead.

Comment: Product recommendations aren't really a good answer, but you can get a USB vacuum cleaner from Walmart for 5 bucks. If you can't afford that then I guess you'll just have to lick the floor.

Comment: This seems like it might be more appropriate on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [Life Hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/). It's really not [DIY/Home-Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: (...looking for the 'kick OP in the keyster' button on this keyboard....)

Answer (score 2):

[image: the invention of the century]

Behold humanity!

I represent the invention of the century...
All your problems soon to be vanished, All you need is getting your self one of these magnificent devices and you will soon realize there is no problem in the world you can not tackle with ease!

Best thing ever happened to Millennials: GIRGIR

GIRGIR's elegant design is combined with ultimate functionality when it comes to dealing with those nasty crumbs trying to avoid their destiny of digestion.

- The brush component is created using 2-petawatt laser pulses from 36 
  different angles for 0.000015 picosecond each to achieve immaculate
  distribution of air flow in all directions.
- Its 100% organic free range space plastic!
- Super Ergonomic Design tested on 400 grand mothers from 17 countries!
- Machine washable, Microwave safe(For heating up yesterdays crumbs)
  and self aware!

Forget about those nonsense brush and dustpan combos taking up space in your nasty looking office cubicle get your self a GIRGIR today!

Now comes with new fancy designs as well!!!
[image: fancy af]

And bigger model for bigger jobs!!!
[image: big af]

Comment: In this case I love the sales pitch.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a brush and a dustpan. Apparently [tough bristles and short quick strokes are the key](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7964/45091). Of course you won't get the carpet completely clean but you can remove all the crumbs and debris that you can see or feel.

I use this method to clean the carpeted stairs in my house because my vacuum cleaner is too bulky to rest on a step. Here is a picture of the kind of brush I use: 
[image: precision scrub brush]

It's called a "precision scrub brush" but if you buy it from a store where they know it by that name you're probably paying too much for it. Just look for it in the cleaning supplies section of your local discount store.

Answer (score 0):

I take some packing or masking tape and make a loop, sticky side out, and sized so it will fit around my slightly spread fingers.  Then I roll it back and forth across the carpet like bulldozer tracks, spreading my fingers slightly to control and tension it.  It takes a knack (or single-direction running) to prevent it unraveling.  When it's full, I turn it inside out or wrap it in a paper towel, throw it out and do it again.

However if I filled up a typically 2"x8" tape, I would instead confront the fact that I have poor eating skills, or are choosing crumbly snacks... and make changes accordingly.  Or just go into the breakroom and eat over the sink.  Otherwise unfortunately without the cleaners, visitors will soon start making judgments!

One reason for poor eating skills is your mind is not on the eating, it is on whatever else you are doing.  That sort of habitual, mindless grazing is a recipe for obesity.  And that is not worth it, considering that you hardly enjoy the food that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to eat at your desk, as is true as you do eat SOMEWHERE, at your home and anywhere else, use a plate, a bowl, etc. Keep paper towels nearby. As you buy the food to eat, you also should be buying utensils to eat with as appropriate. Some bleach cleaner, lysol, paper towels, etc. are things you should own at home, and it sounds like you should own some at work, or bring it in from home every other day.

As far as not being able to afford a vacuum and as odd as it may sound, bring yours in from home. Does work own one that is in a utility closet? Did you ask? If you are that hard up, borrow a family members or friends. It is your mess, so you might actually impress your bosses bringing something in to deal with it. It certainly is not the employers or cleaning crews job to clean your blatant mess. Imagine if you are offended by it, your cohorts most likely are too. Have they said something? The employer and their contracted service personnel are there to clean and keep the place tidy. In the course of doing their cleaning, your mess might get cleaned up, but it is still not their job. Things happen in the course of day to day work that need to be cleaned up, but it is seriously improper for you to "make a mess and leave it for someone else".  This applies to all of us in every facet of our lives.  If this was one crumb, or a few, then you probably wouldn't be asking, because even small crumbs can be cleaned up with bare hands, or a damp/moist towelette.

Take pride in your work area, and set an example for others to follow. In time it could be something that earns you a promotion even if its never spoken of.